# python xpath some but not all columns of a table

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

unfortunately I'm a beginner in XPath and not completly sure how ir works. For a project of mine I'm looking for a way to parse 5 columns of a 9 column table. here is what I got working so far:

```
url="".join(["http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2011_games.html"])

#getting the columns 4-7
page=requests.get(url)
tree=html.fromstring(page.content)
# the //text() is because some of the entries are inside <a></a>s
data = tree.xpath('//table[@id="games"]/tbody/tr/td[position()>3 and position()<8]//text()')
```

so what my workaround idea is, is to just get another list that gets only the first column and then combining the two in an extra step however, that seems unelgegant and unnecessary.

for the XPath I tried so far

```
//table[@id="games"]/tbody/tr/td[position() = 1]/text() | //table[@id="games"]/tbody/tr/td[position()>3 and position()<8]//text()
```

That doesn't include the first column (date) too somehow. (according to w3schools) the | is the operator to connect two XPath statements.

so here is my complete code right now. The data will then be put into two lists as of now.

In hopes that I didn't do anything too stupid, thank you for your help.

```
from lxml import html
import requests


url="".join(["http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1952_games.html"])

page=requests.get(url)
tree=html.fromstring(page.content)
reg_data = tree.xpath('//table[@id="games"]/tbody/tr/td[position() = 1]/text() | //table[@id="games"]/tbody/tr/td[position()>3 and position()<8]//text()')
po_data = tree.xpath('//table[@id="games_playoffs"]/tbody/tr/td[position() = 1]/text() | //table[@id="games_playoffs"]/tbody/tr/td[position()>3 and position()<8]//text()')
n=int(len(reg_data)/5)

if int(year) == 2016:   
    for i in range(0,len(reg_data)):
        if len(reg_data[i])>3 and len(reg_data[i+1])>3:
            n = int((i)/5)
            break    

games=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    games.append([])
    for j in range(0,5):
        games[i].append(reg_data[5*i+j])

po_games=[]
m=int(len(po_data)/5)
if year != 2016:
    for i in range(0,m):
        po_games.append([])
        for j in range(0,5):
            po_games[i].append(po_data[5*i+j])

print(games)
print(po_games)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a lot of the data is wrapped in link (a) tags so that when you are asking for text node children, you aren't finding any because you need to go one level deeper.

Instead of

```
/text()
```

do

```
//text()
```

The two slashes means to select text() nodes which are decendants at ANY level.

You can also combine the entire expression into

```
//table[@id="games"]/tbody/tr/td[position() = 1 or (position()>3 and position()<8)]//text()
```

instead of having two expressions.

We can even shorten further to

```
//table[@id="games"]//td[position() = 1 or (position()>3 and position()<8)]//text()
```

but there is a risk to this expression, as it will pick up td elements which occur anywhere in the table (provided they are a 1st, 4th, 5th, 6th, or 7th column), not just in rows in the body.  In your target this will work, however.

Note also that an expression like `[position()=1]` is not necessary.  You can shorten it to `[1]`.  You only need the position function if you need the position of a node other than the context node, or need to write a more complex selection like we have when needing more than just one specific index.